# Vue Vee validate in Laravel method unique

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Laravel validate has method `unique` but vue-vee validate doesn't has it. How can i use `unique` in vue-vee validate? (I mean `v-validate=''`)
For example in laravel:

```
 return $validator = [
  'title' => 'required|unique:rubrics,title',
];
```

In advance thanks for help.

Comment: [_"The field under validation must be unique in a given database table."_](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-unique) This makes sense in the backend, but within Vue, it doesn't really makes sense unless you manually compare to an array or collection.

Comment: You can roll your own back end unique validation. https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/advanced.html#backend-example

Comment: Emile Bergeron, thank you.How can i able to do it  via props=[]?

Comment: I'm sorry but I have to say that it's way too broad to ask on Stack Overflow. We are not a code writing service and even if we were, there's so much information missing in your question that it's still unclear what you want.

Comment: Take a look in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to get started on Stack Overflow. Look at other good questions on the site to get the feeling of what works well when asking for help. Good luck! ;)